# Quaternion process noise in EKF

Tags: control-theory, quaternions, kalman-filter

I'm learning about Extended Kalman Filters for position and orientation estimation and I found the documentation for the OpenIMU project to be a good resource because it shows a step-by-step derivation that I haven't seen elsewhere.

I'm now working through the [Quaternion State-Transition Model](https://openimu.readthedocs.io/en/latest/algorithms/STM_Quaternion.html) page and there are a few things I don't quite understand in the derivation of the process noise covariance matrix.

It says that the quaternion process-noise vector is
$$\vec{w}_{q,k-1} = -{{dt} \over {2}} \cdot \Omega_{noise,k-1} \cdot \vec{q}_{k-1}$$
This makes sense to me given the preceding derivation, but then in the next step this is rewritten as
$$\vec{w}_{q,k-1} = -{{dt} \over {2}} \cdot \Xi_{k-1} \cdot \vec{\omega}_{noise}^{B}$$
with
$$\Xi_{k-1} \equiv \begin{bmatrix} {
                                   \begin{array}{c}
                                                    {-\vec{q}_{v}^{T}} \\
                                                    {q_0 \cdot I_3 + \begin{bmatrix} {\vec{q}_{v} \times} \end{bmatrix}}
                                   \end{array}
                 } \end{bmatrix}$$
where $\begin{bmatrix} {\vec{q}_{v} \times} \end{bmatrix}$ is "the cross-product matrix".

My questions are: how is this equation derived, what is this $\Xi_{k-1}$ matrix and what is a cross-product matrix?

---

I don't know if this is relevant but I found that the equation given earlier for the quaternion state transition
$$\vec{q}_{k} = { \begin{bmatrix} {
                                  I_4 + {{dt} \over {2}} \cdot \Omega_{true,k-1}
                } \end{bmatrix}
              } \cdot {\vec{q}}_{k-1}$$
is equivalent to pre-multiplying the previous state ${\vec{q}}_{k-1}$ with a quaternion with elements $$[x, y, z, w] = \Bigg[\frac{dt}{2}\omega_{true,x}^B, \frac{dt}{2}\omega_{true,y}^B, \frac{dt}{2}\omega_{true,z}^B, 1\Bigg]$$

Maybe something similar is used here?

Comment: The cross product matrix is an alternative way to compute the cross product by writing it as a matrix product instead. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product#Conversion_to_matrix_multiplication